# Invalid or unexpected token - with a simple message generation

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is really simple stuff but cannot see what im missing, any ideas?

error: Invalid or unexpected token

Getting the error on the message var im trying to build

JS

```
var country_select = 'c_UK';
  var country_image = 'eu';
  var country_link = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
  var country_short = 'UK';

  var message = "looks like you're in" + json.country + "<span class='flag-" + country_image +"'></span> Take me to the Google <span class='"+ country_found_short +"'></span> site <a href='"+ country_link +"' class='button country_found_link'>Visit Site</a>';

  // set top bat details
  $(".country-select .message").html(message);
  $(".country_found_short").html(country_short);
  $(".country-select").show();
```

Comment: You need a double-quote before the semicolon here: `Visit Site</a>';`

Comment: Sorry, knew it was something stupid! been a long day lol

Comment: Happens to us all : )